# Rtrt stub for an input parameter of an array

Tags: rtrt

I have a stub like  "void read(uint8 _inout data[5]); " .Now I need to expect a value 2 for data[3]. I have done multiple methods like below
 "stub read((0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,2)) "
"stub read({0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,2})

but none of them are working.
Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Your array `data[5]` has 5 element so I believe this should work:

***STUB read 1=> ({0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,2,0})***

You could also create 2 arrays and pass to the stub:

***ARRAY in_array, INIT = 0, EV ==***

***ARRAY out_array, INIT = (0 => 0, 1=> 0, 2=> 0, 3=>2, others=>0), EV ==***

***STUB read((in_array, out_array))***